# how to create log file and to log data upto level of max 2mb next to generate new file by using c#

Tags: c#

trying to create log file in my window service application,to log information,error's as well,so each file has to log the data up to 2 mb max soon after it was finished it should create new log file in the same path,by over writing a file name of appending timestamp and start log into new file,can any one please suggest on the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) and you can achieve this using the [rolling file appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html).

You configure it through your config file (app.config or web.config) as follows:

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt and valuable reply, the same how can i call in code behind wise, please show some sample to log info and error, one doubt,this log file can we set our own path,can i use for each thread one log file ? please suggest

Comment: Take a look at this sample http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8245/A-Brief-Introduction-to-the-log4net-logging-librar. It will show you how go get started. Yes, you can set your own path in <file value="log.txt" />. Take a look at the options supported by rolling file appender, there are many. It would be simpler to write all logs to one file and then filter by thread id.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use any existing logging framework like [NLOG](http://nlog.codeplex.com/) for logging rather than rolling out your own, it has all the features you have mentioned.